# Use Perl to filter out the word "a" but not each letter "a"

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am trying to write a regular expression in Perl to filter out the word 'a' in a string but not each occurrence of the letter 'a'.  For example, if I have the string "I saw a fat cat",

```
my $string = "I saw a fat cat";
```

I want the filtered string to be "I saw fat cat", but I'm getting "I sw ft ct".  I have tried variations of this expression:

```
$string=~ s/a//g;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `\b` delimiter for word boundaries:

```
$string =~ s/\ba\b//g;
```

Note that this will only get rid of the `a`, it won't get rid of the spaces next to it. If you wanted a properly spaced sentence, you'd probably want to use something like this (which would remove the leading space before the `a` as well, but leave the trailing one to prevent the before and after words from being pushed together):

```
$string =~ s/\s*\ba\b//g;
```